# a way to track all the components that are called in a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need a way to track all the component calls when a page renders, for example if my page is like:

```
<MyPage>
   <A />
   <B>
      <B2/>
      <B3>
   </B>
   <C /> // witch the component C, calls D in its own code
</MyPage>
```

and C is like:

```
<C>
   <D />
</C>
```

something like that, witch a bunch of nested components are called for a page to be rendered, I need a list of all of them, in this example, I need (A, B, B2, B3, C, D),

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the React Developer Tools addon ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/))? That will add a "Components" tab to your developer tools, which looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of React Developer Tools]

You can then select any component to get more details about it as well.

Comment: thank you, completely forgot about dev tools

Answer (score 0):

It's like you asking something already done in React Chrome extension,which is an open source project..
When you looked into its main.js file https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions/src/main.js
Which got some noticable imports

import {
getAppendComponentStack,
getBreakOnConsoleErrors,
getSavedComponentFilters,
getShowInlineWarningsAndErrors,
} from 'react-devtools-shared/src/utils';

I think what you need is must be inside getAppendComponentStack Utility..
Check also this https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-devtools-shared/src/utils.js

Sure you will workout a solution with some analysis..

#using Mobile edition.. Please bear with the format of the answer.